# Fastest Way to Find Option Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor, drop-down-menu

I have a .Net Core 2.2 app that is using a select list to let the user choose what account they want to view.

here is an example of that select list

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-left" id="tour-dropdown">
    <p>Choose an account</p>
    <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-white" data-live-search="true" data-width="fit" data-size="5">
        @if (Model.IsClient)
        {
            <option value="-1|false">View All Accounts</option>
        }
        @foreach (var item in Model.AccountList)
        {
            <option value="@item.AccountValue">@item.AccountName (@item.AccountCode)</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

When they change the dropdown I have a jquery script that looks for it and changes the screen accordingly.

```
$('.selectpicker').on('change', function (ev, picker) {

    var selectedAccount = $(this).find("option:selected").val();

    window.location.href = "/gohere";
});
```

The issue is when my select list has a lot of accounts in it 10K+ that `var selectedAccount = $(this).find("option:selected").val();` seems to lock up the page for a few seconds before it does anything.

I have used `asp-for` on select lists before and it seems much quicker, only issue is that I have some Javascript variables I add to the redirect which I can't really control through the asp-for.

Does anyone know a faster way of finding the selected account on change for a select list?

Comment: Did you try: `$(this).val();` ?

Comment: That does seem to be faster, thanks!